# Any good reasources on zermelo fraenkel set theory?

Tags: set-theory

Any good resources on zermelo-Frankel-Sey theory stuff like papers, links and other educational resources would be useful Also, can someone help me understand in simple terms what exactly it is?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Zermelo's 1930 Axiomatization of Set Theory is relevent, as its the final form of his initial attempt 30 years earlier. : https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Akihiro-Kanamori/publication/226238554_Zermelo_1930a/links/5432aa6b0cf225bddcc7c420/Zermelo-1930a.pdf?origin=publication_detail&_tp=eyJjb250ZXh0Ijp7ImZpcnN0UGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uIiwicGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uRG93bmxvYWQiLCJwcmV2aW91c1BhZ2UiOiJwdWJsaWNhdGlvbiJ9fQ